# Spotify implicit flow tutorial, token is null

Tags: reactjs, spotify

New developer here trying to create a spotify search project to help me learn.

I'm following this tutorial so a user can log into my app using spotify.
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-build-a-spotify-player-with-react-in-15-minutes-7e01991bc4b6

I am currently stuck at the section where it asks where you create the login button. I've followed the code examples, but when i load the page i get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of null
Landing.render
src/components/Landing.js:39
  36 | }
  37 | render() {
  38 |   return (
> 39 |     <div className="Landing">
     | ^  40 |       {!this.state.token && (
  41 |       <a
  42 |         className="btn btn--loginApp-link"
```

Here is what my code looks like

```
import './Landing.scss';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export const authUrl = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';

const clientId = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000";
const scopes = [
  "user-read-currently-playing",
  "user-read-playback-state",
];

const hash = window.location.hash
  .substring(1)
  .split("&")
  .reduce(function (initial, item) {
    if (item) {
      var parts = item.split("=");
      initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
    }
    return initial;
  }, {});
window.location.hash = "";

class Landing extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let _token = hash.access_token;
    console.log(_token)
    if (_token) {
      this.setState({
        token: _token
      });
    } else {
      console.log("no token")
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Landing">
        {!this.state.token && (
        <a
          className="btn btn--loginApp-link"
          href={`${authUrl}client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join("%20")}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`}
        >
          Login to Spotify
        </a>
      )}
      {this.state.token && (
        console.log("hello")
      )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Landing;
```

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: It would appear that your state is not being set. What is the output from this line ```console.log(_token)```?

Comment: It is undefined.

Comment: Ye, so the state is not set. 
If ```_token``` is undefined then ```this.setState()``` is never run. I presume then that you see "no token" being printed?

Comment: Yeah but im not sure why its null. As i said im quite fresh to coding. But im following this tutorial i mentioend above and it seems to be exactly what he set, so im not sure why i'd be seeing this error

Comment: Well, it's because ```this.state``` is undefined. If you were open up your console in Chrome's developer tools and type ```this.state.token``` you would get the exact same error as there is no ```this.state``` thus impossible that there is ```this.state.token```. Have you tried removing the if - ```if (_token) {```?

Comment: Yeah if i remove that it can load properly, but for the actual tutorial it seems i will need the token. I feel like removing that will just cause problems in the following steps

Comment: I've just looked at the next step in the tutorial. If you actually continue with the next step it will solve your problem. The author creates the ```constructor()``` for the component and initializes the state there. If you go ahead with the next step you should have no problems :)

Comment: Thanks! you're right that does work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error, is that the initial state values are not defined. So react sets `this.state` to `null`, thus you get the error.

How to solve the issue ?

1. You set the default state in the constructor, this way `this.state` is not `null`

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      token: ""
    };
  }
```

2. you check if the state is not null (or just not a falsy value) and you render what you need

```
{this.state && !this.state.token && (...
```

And from the tutorial that you showed, you can see that the person actually declares a default state in the next code example

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      token: null,
    item: {
      album: {
        images: [{ url: "" }]
      },
      name: "",
      artists: [{ name: "" }],
      duration_ms:0,
    },
    is_playing: "Paused",
    progress_ms: 0
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this does help